# how to add some kind of delay in javascript, race condition between href and onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, href, delay, conditional-statements

the problem there seems to be a race condition between href and onclick in some browsers like chrome and ie9, so i wanted onclick to run first and then return to one button url, so i wrote the code

```
 function track_cb(link) {  
  Cancel();     
 //alert(window.location.href);
  return true;
   }
```

i modified  href kind of like this

```
  <A HREF="some button url" onclick="return            
   track_cb(this);"
```

after cancel(), i need some time so that button url executes next, how to properly achieve this ?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Could you rephrase please?

Comment: I need to return to a button URL, I add some text in some text area say and click on that button, then i need to clear some locks on that record first and then go to the button url, but in some browsers the cancel operation was not getting executed, so  wrote the above, hope it is clear, first it was kind of like onclick="cancel()", so i modified it

Comment: Could you just rephrase the following one : "I need to return to a button URL"? "return" like the `return` keyword?

Comment: ok let me make it clear, I open 1 ticket, enter some data in description field but without saving it, I click on 'home' button, in some browsers when i do this, as the ticket is in edit mode, the lock is not getting cleared and it will return to the home page, this i observed due to cancel() call was not getting properly executed, so I added above code hoping first cleanup the locks and give some little time to get to that href,

Comment: It sounds like you want to block the click, wait for your method to finish, and then proceed to the URL. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the href attribute and at the end of the function insert a javascript command to go to the url. Use callback if the function takes a long time to execute (eg it retrieves something from another webpage/server).